# We need more question, so move your heads and go to work!

Tags: discussion, questions, beta

[We are endangered site](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66/private-beta-extended-to-two-weeks-site-needs-quality-and-quantity) so we need to ask more questions in order to survive!

I try to ask as many questions as possible, but operating without my expertise range. I'm asking questions targeting European realities, and mostly IT issues.

There are a lot of questions, which are not universal, but they target the particular region (Europe, America, Asia, Africa) or the particular freelance/contractor activity (development, webmastering, translations, tourist guiding, transport). So I suggest, that anyone familiar to particular region and branch should pick a few questions and adapt them to their environment.

For example, a question about IT contractor wanting to find contract in another EU country could be easily adapted as the tourist guide from Mexico who wants to organize city guides in Canada.

We just need a few dozen questions to get started, so anyone who wants this site to start, please join that action!

Comment: The thing is, we also need those questions to be high quality and not just questions for the sake of getting more questions on the site. Need to find that balance, which is proving tricky within this field

Comment: We have made it, thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I agree with Keelan, I think there is room for more involvement.

There are a few things I have been trying to do to create new questions.

1. Are there questions I had that I didn't get adequate answers at the time for when I started my business?  How would I answer them today?  These are great candidates for self-answered questions.
2. Are there questions I had that I think I have an answer to today but I am not sure?  These are good questions.
3. Are there questions I wish I had when starting out that others should think to ask?  Again, candidates for self-answered questions.

Yes, I do think there is room for more involvement.  No I don't think it needs to be gaming the system.  Part of what we need to do is to come up with questions that set the tone of the site.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to ask everyone to engage as normally in this site.

When that isn't enough to proceed to public beta, so be it.

Gaming the system isn't a good idea and won't work out.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with @Keelan's opinion, but there are several considerations I'd like to share.

### We don't just need more questions.

Don't kill me now, let me explain.

The majority of the users are active freelancers. [43% have committed as Experts](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37227?phase=commitment&committers=userreputation#tab-top); it's a huge difference comparing to other SE sites where the majority are Enthusiasts or so.
So we *do* know the answers simply because we solve those problems for ourselves.

We can "cheat" the system by asking questions we know answers for, but this would be a limited help.

**What we really need is new people.** Those who are trying to be freelancers, who are facing real problems, and who can formulate those problems into questions. So let's go and promote.

---

### Voting is a key for private beta.

[Barely 60 of us](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users?page=2&tab=reputation&filter=all) have ever earned a point. [Only 29 users](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all) have **ever** voted here.

While in private beta, the whole scope of the site is determined by votes of several hundred people.
Vote up or down, but *do* express your opinion about the most of questions and answers.

---

Don't refrain from asking "bad" questions. Try pushing the limits of the original scope. If the community decides that a certain question is offtopic, so be it. Several downvotes are easily compensated with a single upvote.

Comment: actually, [we *are* in public beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37227/freelancing) - start inviting people! :)

Comment: Good point that we need more people, but you can get more people once you leave private beta, which we finally have done, even if with the means of cheating the system a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some experts here, maybe the key is attracting more newcomers (like me) to start asking questions that we ask to ourselves. I think this way we will have the experts answering questions rather than asking them, and this may lead to better content.