# Updated Help Center - On Topic

Tags: discussion, site-topic, help-center

I went ahead and updated the [Help Center list of topics](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Freelancing Stack Exchange is for **Self-employed and freelance workers**.
>
> **If your question covers...**
>
> - Agency work while freelancing
> - Selling services to different employers without a long-term contract with any of them
> - Client responsibilities to freelancers
> - Cross-border requirements and laws for freelancing
>
> **and isn't about...**
>
> - Working in a part-time of full-time setting for a company
> - Asking for life experiences or opinions on freelancing
>
> ...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Please [look around](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s
> also OK to [ask and answer your own question](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/self-answer).

In order to become a site for experts, we'll need to specialize. What else is our list of topics missing?

What about things we *don't* do.  It's just as important to define what our site is *not* about.  What else do we add to the list?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what I already added, I also added a "How should I answer" section to highlight the back it up rule.

> ### How should I answer?
>
> Your answer should provide enough context to help the asker determine if the answer is right for them. Answers based on facts, references, and specific expertise are preferable.
>
> If the question has the [legal](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) tag, you should include references or citations to back up your answer.
>
> In general, your answer should always include material to support or explain why your answer is correct. Answers that don't meet these guidelines may be removed. For more information, see [the back it up rule](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/should-this-site-have-a-back-it-up-rule).

There are some answers on legal questions with no way to validate them, and I've begun the process of leaving comments, applying post notices, and even editing posts that I think can be saved.