# Closed Posts Deletion -- and How To Help Clean Up Posts

Tags: discussion, voting, vote-to-close

We have a lot of closed posts on our main page this month. This isn't anything to be concerned about, necessarily. It just means people posted content that isn't fit for Stack Exchange Q&A or that isn't on topic. We close these posts to give askers, and the community, a chance to improve this content via clarifying questions in the comments and editing, so we get the askers, as well as the freelancing community, the best answers possible.

To reduce the clutter and keep our site looking clean, attractive, and professional, I deleted the closed posts for this month that were older than 5 days, where it was clear the asker wasn't going to return to edit and improve the post.

If you have 2,000+ reputation, you can review the list of [recently deleted posts in the 2k moderator tools](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last7days), and bring anything up on meta that might be worth salvaging.

To continue to grow our site, creating a high quality repository of freelancing knowledge is key. Attractive, clean, crisp, content backed by facts, references, and specific expertise draws people in from search engines and provides them with definitive answers to their questions. Our goal is for people to leave *knowing* that they have a verifiable solution, thanks to our site's [back it up guidelines](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/55/64).

If you don't have 2,000 reputation, you can still help us be the best site on the Internet for solving freelancing problems. Here's what you can do:

- [Vote to close posts](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) that are unclear, too broad, or off-topic.
- [Leave comments asking posters questions that help them clarify their post](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). If it's unclear, ask questions and encourage them to edit. Don't answer the post until enough information is there to where you can post an answer that solves a deeper problem.
- **[Use your votes](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)**. Down vote low quality content so it doesn't appear at the top of the page, and up vote quality content. Voting is the most powerful tool at our disposal for ensuring only the best content rises to the top.
- Use your reopen votes to [help get edited and improved posts taken off hold and reopened](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) for more answers.  Use our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8874/freelancing) and [meta](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/) to gain more reopen vote support from other community members.
- If you see what might be unclear about a post and think you can clarify it, go ahead and [give the post an edit](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/editing). Editing is the most powerful feature on Stack Exchange. With the editing tools, we can transform our content into high quality questions and answers that will help future visitors for years to come. Remember, questions posted here don't just help a single asker, they also should ideally help the thousands of people who will also search for that same problem and land on that page.
- Lastly, if you don't have privileges yet to do any of these things, remember that you can make a suggested edit, or you can [flag the post](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).